# Balancing resistance circuit with two voltage sources

Tags: resistance, control, bridge, balancing

[image]

Hello, first I'm not sure if the title describes well enough the problem. I have the following circuit. Left side is a part of a voltage regulator.
Point A has a fixed potential of 1.2V (a feedback pin of voltage regulator IC). When this points potential is trying to change, U1 changes in order to compensate for the change, so point A continue to stay at 1.2V. In the actual circuit R1 is a 100k rheostat which controls U1.  The right part of the bridge is mine addition. I have second voltage source U2 with fixed value of 5V, and a two resistors, which are actually part of potentiometer.
I want to fix R1 and change U1 between 1.2V and 14V by changing the ratio of R3/R4.
So the two pictures below show the two borderline conditions with their currents.
By trial and error I found these values: R1 is fixed to 41k, and R3/R4 varies between 10k/16.5k and 20k/6.5k (which in practice can be done with 10k resistor + 10k potentiometer + 6.5k resistor).
The problem with this circuit and these values is that the control is not linear. In the table below you can see that the curve has S shape (V column is actually U1 voltage)
Please, can someone help me - what modification to the circuit or the values should I make in order to linearize the control? Or at least to move the part with the smaller delta towards the smaller U.
Note - I have only 10k and 50k digital potentiometers at disposal, so it should be done somehow with one of them.

Comment: I think I understood most of it except _”linearize the control”_. Can you explain what more than just choosing a resistor divider ratio to get 5 V at all times with a Vref of 1.2 V which you need, and why?

Comment: @winni Hi, with the given values the control of U1 is not linear. You can see the S shape of the U1. R3/R4 is changing in linear way, but dU1 change is not linear. For example I want with every 1k change of a 10k potentiometer to have change of U1 with equal step of (14-1.2)/10.

Comment: But that’s only down to how you’ve drawn your circuit. What’s your end goal? Do you have a variable input voltage and want to regulate to a fixed 5 V output?

Comment: Why not just have the R1-R2 resistor divider? Why do you need R3-R4 and U2 to achieve this? You can make R2 a fixed resistor and just vary R1. The voltage will linearly vary with R1

Comment: @winny 
R1 - R2 devider is the original devider that sets the feedback of a voltage regulator. U1 is the output voltage of the regulator. So, there is a voltage drop over R1 which is between U1-1.2V. When you change R1, you change the current through R2, thus changing the1.2V. The regulator sense this and change the output voltage U1 in order to get R2 voltage back to 1.2. I cannot replace R1 with dig. potentiometer, because the max allowed voltage over it is 5V. This is why I introduce the right part - in order to inject additional current in R2.

Comment: @sai - look at the comment above

Comment: What output voltage range of the regulator do you want to cover with the external control?

Comment: @Jens - 1.2 - 14V, as shown on the two circuit pictures

Comment: Sorry, I don’t follow. Please draw black box with inputs and outputs. Draw a truth table or graph how you want your output(s) to respond depending on inputs. Leave out all steps how to implement it.

Comment: @winni this is the actual circuit of the regulator:
https://cdn.hackaday.io/images/6122801651248968959.jpg

Look at the Rtv - Rfb1 devider down there. Those are R2 - R1 on the circuit in this post. Vop is U1. When you turn Rtv, you are changing Vop. The point between Rtc and Rfb1 stays all the time at 1.21V. I want to digitize this regulator, but cannot do it by simply exchanging Rtv with digital potentiometer, because the voltage drop over Rtv is Vop - 1.21, which can become much higher than 5V, which is the maximum voltage you can use with dig. potenciometer.

Comment: @winni So, if I cannot vary Rtv (R1 here). the only other way to move the Vop is by injecting current in Rfb1 (R2 here), in order to move its potential. The IC will sense this and will change Vop (U1) in order to balance the voltages in a such way that 1.21V is constant. How can I vary the current? By adding the dig. potentiometer in additional circuit (R3-R4) which is powered by U2 = 5V.  So the circuit in the post is just this - simulation of the resulting bridge. When you change R1/R2 ratio you change the current through R2, which change U1 to the necessary value to keep point A at 1.21V

Comment: @winni - So the main problem can be summarized like this - how and with what resistances should I construct the additional circuit in order to be able to achieve linear change of U1 (between 1.2 and 14V) when I change a potentiometer in a linear way (between 0 and 10k or 0 and 50k). Apparently this is not achieved in the above circuit, probably because the two shoulders have different weights over the resulting current in R2, and also because the right shoulder is different than the left one

Comment: Actually the problem here is that the right shoulder has two branches and the left branch current (which is injected in R2) doesn't change linearly when R3/R4 ratio is changed.

Answer (score 0):

In these circuits OA1 represents the step down converter regulation loop and V1 is the internal reference voltage.

If you want to use a DAC, this circuit will provide a linear relation between the DAC value (V2) and the output voltage. The time domain analysis of this simulator shows the results.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2frtyPS.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

If you prefer the digital potentiometer, you need a buffer amplifier (OA2) for a linear relation. The DC sweep analysis of this simulator shows the results.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fB5TQm.png)</sup>

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot! I forgot about using opamp as a voltage follower. Do you think that the first circuit will work well if V2 is a pwm pin with a capacitor in paralel?
Actually in the beginning I wanted to control the step down converter by current, but digital potentiometer didn't work well in the feedback loop of the opamp ( https://cdn.hackaday.io/images/6122801651248968959.jpg ). The circuit became very unstable, the current was drifting both fast and slowly and it was susceptible to disturbances. When I was touching the insulated mosfet heatsinks, the current was changing a lot.

Comment: @irilinir A PWM output followed by an R/C filter has some source impedance (>= 1 kohm in practice) and will affect the linearity of your circuit without a buffer. I would prefer either the second circuit version or compensate the linearity error by calculations in software.

Comment: thanks for the comments. I started to execute the second variant. The only cons is that I need to power the opamp (LM358) with voltage bigger than 5V, because the output is about 1.3 V lower then  the source. Too many step down convertors for the whole device - first main supply 220->24V, then 24->12V for some fans and this amp, then 12->5V for the relays and arduino+modules. And the variable converter from 24 to 1.2-14 V :)

Comment: @irilinir you can find another resistor combination of R3 and R2 that will work with 3.3 V if your buffer amplifier is not rail to rail. 24 V fans are popular as well.

Comment: may you look at the circuit of the step down regulator, which I posted few comments ago and think about some other way of digitizing the current control different than just replacing Rtc with dig. potentiometer?

Comment: @irilinir The current limiter works different. It is a variable gain amplifier, that provides soft current limit. I think, you should make another question out of that.

Comment: I know how it works, but the problem is that it doesn't work well with a digital potentiometer in the feedback of the opamp. Unstable, drifting current, susceptible to disturbances. I made another discussion about this a while ago, but there weren't many replies.

Comment: I tried the  opamp follower, but it behaves a little strange. As I said I use LM358, powered by 12V. Despite of this, the output doesn't follow the input as I expect. Here is what I get: (4,91-> 4,42); (4,27->3,93); (3,63->3,35); (2,99->2,81); (2,35->2,18); (1,72->1,65); (1,26->1,25); (0,88->0,92); (0.5->0,6); (0,02->0,11)
So you can see, that with the rising of the input voltate, the difference between the output and input becomes bigger - the output voltage drops further. This measurements are taken with no load connected to the opamp output.